# Flutter timezone package tz.local not getting the accurate time of my region

Tags: flutter, dart, timezone

I am trying to get the local timezone in my Flutter project
I imported the timezone package and did this

```
import 'package:timezone/data/latest.dart' as tz;
import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart' as tz;

tz.initializeTimeZones();
print(tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local));
```

it did print 2023-11-15 13:24:22 but my actual time is 2023-11-15 15:24:22

Answer (score 0):

In the above code, replace `'Asia/Kolkata'` with your `timezone`

```
    tz.initializeTimeZones();
    tz.setLocalLocation(tz.getLocation('Asia/Kolkata'));
    print(tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local).toString());
```

In `Flutter`, you can use the `DateTime.now()` function to get the current `date` and `time` in the **user’s local timezone**.

Comment: But I don't need it to get the time in Asia, I just need to get the accurate time of whatever country the user is from

Comment: I updated my response.